# Easy way to cache request with parameters?

Tags: php, apache, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

Application context:

1. frontend performs a get request to my api endpoint (php file)
2. my api request the data from a third party api which has a requests/minute limit.

A typical request looks like this: api/movies/m=godfather.

What i am trying to do is to avoid executing the script if the request was fetched like 5 min ago and run it if never requested before.

I know there is a way to do this, by saving the result to a file and check the file before re-fetching in the next request, but i was wondering if there were a better way to do this like caching using http headers to cache request depending on the parameters used in the requests.

So the end result should be:

1. api/movies?m=godfather => cache
2. api/movies?m=transformers => fetch

Comment: redis and memcache are two options that are exceedingly good at solving this specific issue.

Comment: You can use [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/) (or similar) to sit in front of your API server and cache requests.

Comment: I dont have a lot of knowledge in redis, so i wont be able to setup and use redis. However i like to use a simple solution, like using the apache server to cache the request but not sure how or if it is possible